# pandas.DataFrame.value_counts : How to sort results based upon separate list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of labels, labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and a dataframe with each row consisting of an index followed by one of these letters. Some letters are repeated, whereas others may not even appear. I'm looking for the best way to produce a list of four numbers, where each entry counts the number of occurrences of the letter and where the ordering is prescribed the labels.

```
import pandas as pd
labels=['a','b','c','d']
occurrences=['d','d','b','c','b','d','b','c','c','d','b','d'] 
#Observe that 'a' never appears.
df = pd.DataFrame(occurrences,columns=['occurences'])
counts=df['occurences'].value_counts()
```

Here, counts will produce a series(?) whose columns are b,d,c and 5,4,3. What I want is the list
[0,5,3,4]

Answer (score 2):

You can `reindex` the Series returned by `value_counts`:

```
In [337]: counts.reindex(labels).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[337]:
a    0
b    4
c    3
d    5
Name: occurences, dtype: int32
```

If you just want the values, you can cast it to a list:

```
In [339]: list(counts.reindex(labels).fillna(0).astype(int))
Out[339]: [0, 4, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you